# Keep theorem heading up when followed by centered content

Tags: theorems

(I am sure this question has already been asked. I just couldn't find it.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, tikz}
\newtheoremstyle{solutionstyle}
        {12pt}{8ex}{\normalfont}{}{\bfseries}{\normalfont\bfseries\vspace{3ex}}{\newline}{}
\theoremstyle{solutionstyle}
\newtheorem{solution}{Solution}

\begin{document}
\begin{solution}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=4];
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{center}
\end{solution}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What is the suggested way to keep `my theorem` heading up where it is supposed to be, when it is immediately followed by a centered image, etc.

Comment: Nasty trick: add `\item` before `\begin{center}`. AFAIK both theorems and `center` are actually lists. And if the item is empty the next list does not go to a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't start an environment based on `trivlist`, such as `center`, immediately after `\begin{solution}`.

However, you don't really want `center`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, tikz}

\newtheoremstyle{solutionstyle}
  {12pt}
  {8ex}
  {\normalfont}
  {}
  {\bfseries}
  {\normalfont\bfseries\vspace{3ex}}
  {\newline}
  {}
\theoremstyle{solutionstyle}
\newtheorem{solution}{Solution}

\begin{document}

\begin{solution}
$x=1$
\end{solution}

\begin{solution}\mbox{}
\begin{center}
Obvious\\
to\\
everybody
\end{center}
\end{solution}

\begin{solution}\mbox{}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=2];
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{center}
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There's too much blank space left. You may want to use (or abuse) `\[...\]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, tikz}

\newtheoremstyle{solutionstyle}
  {12pt}
  {8ex}
  {\normalfont}
  {}
  {\bfseries}
  {\normalfont\bfseries\vspace{3ex}}
  {\newline}
  {}
\theoremstyle{solutionstyle}
\newtheorem{solution}{Solution}

\begin{document}

\begin{solution}
$x=1$
\end{solution}

\begin{solution}
\[
\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=2];
\end{tikzpicture}}
\]
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

(`\fbox` added for better showing the vertical space).

[image]